# What algorithm is more efficient in computing eigenvectors?

Tags: performance, algorithm, eigenvector, eigenvalue

I need to find all eigenpairs of a symmetric real matrix. Quick search shows that there are 5 main algorithms doing that:

1. Jacobi rotations. Every researcher says it's ineffective.
2. QR. My textbook says it's the best way.
3. Divide-and-conquer. Wikipedia says it's better than QR.
4. MRRR. Never ever heard of it. Any paper seems incomprehensible to me. However, it's newer than DnC, so it must be faster.
5. Homotopy method. Don't know anything on that.

2, 3 and 4 require the said matrix to be first brought to Hessenberg form. My question is, which one of those is actually the best? I failed to find a paper with a desired comparsion. Moreover, some papers are behind a paywall. Behind that, I tried to read LAPACK code, but this seems impossible as it is optimised as hell. I need your help!

Comment: The algorithm of choice will depends on the sparseness and size of the matrix. If you wanted to implement only 1 algorithm then there will be cases where the algorithm will be inefficient and on average you will have a high complexity O(...). Lapack actually selects an algorithm based on the provided matrix so you may have to implement something similar if you want the most efficient solution. Even combining 2 algorithms, one for sparse and non-spare matrices, will result in a vastly better solution.

Comment: Rank is also important, because if you have only a few eigenvalues, it can be more efficient to compute the eigenvalues using power iterations rather than factorizing the matrix.

Comment: In any case, I think that the practical thing to do is to use an off-the-shelf eigensolver, rather than trying to implement one yourself based on a research article.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! That's why i'm trying to implement it - because I can't use a third-party library. As for the matrix, it's a simple correlation matrix. Maybe a covariation one in the future, but nothing sparse or otherwise special.

Comment: "it's newer than ..., so it must be faster"...? Vacuous logic alert!

Comment: @twalberg See, why would they invent a new algorithm if the older worked just fine? It's got to do something better. Solid logic I think.

Comment: So the bottom line is probably that you should give us more details like the sizes of the matrices you want to diagonalize, the type of their entries, whether you need all eigenvalues or not, your time constraints, ...
I hardly see a case for coding anything complicated here, as the details in most of the algorithms are tricky and you may lose a lot of coding time in debugging and a lot of computing time because of sub-optimized subroutines. So if it were me I would either go with the simplest Jacobi algorithm or use packages like lapack (which are free)

Comment: @Atmaks solid logic but probably not (public) research logic

Comment: @Atmaks Some algorithms are noticably slower on smaller problems, but faster on larger, or they're better for particular types of data sets (e.g. tri-diagonal matrices); or maybe they're more accurate for near-singular matrices, but slower - the improved accuracy may be a valid reason to still use that algorithm instead of others. In short, "newer" is generally "better" in some sense (but not always), but the way in which it is "better" may not be "faster across the board for all problem types and sizes"...

Comment: @Atmaks Why can't you use 3rd party libraries? Lapacke has a completely free to use licence, you can even include the package in commercial software for sale, without any restrictions. Plus whatever Lapacke does, it will almost certainly be faster than anything you can code yourself, especially since the underlying CBLAS library it relies on has compile options that allow you to optimize routines for your particular system, i.e. it will compile different on different systems in order to give maximum speed.